# how to add js in custom form in backend magento 2

Tags: magento2, javascript, forms

I have used this code in my form to manage the field id_pdt that is a foreign key  so i will put a text from bar code and then search in mu custom table to find if the sku exists in table product and then save in table the id of this product but i get this error Cannot read property 'value' of null and here is my code

```
              <?php
             namespace BO\Paquet\Block\Adminhtml\Paquet\Edit;

            use \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Form\Generic;

         class Form extends Generic
        {

/**
 * @var \Magento\Store\Model\System\Store
 */
protected $_systemStore;


/**
 * @var \Magento\Store\Model\System\Store
 */
protected $_produit;

/**
 * @param \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context
 * @param \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry
 * @param \Magento\Framework\Data\FormFactory $formFactory
 * @param \Magento\Store\Model\System\Store $systemStore
 * @param \BO\Prix\Model\Source\Family $family
 * @param \BO\Prix\Model\Source\Choix $choix
 * @param array $data
 */
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
    \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
    \Magento\Framework\Data\FormFactory $formFactory,
    \Magento\Store\Model\System\Store $systemStore,
       /*        \BO\Paquet\Model\Source\Produit $produit,*/
    array $data = []
) {
    $this->_systemStore = $systemStore;


    parent::__construct($context, $registry, $formFactory, $data);
}

/**
 * Init form
 *
 * @return void
 */
protected function _construct()
{
    parent::_construct();
    $this->setId('paquet_form');
    $this->setTitle(__('Packet Informations'));
}

/**
 * Prepare form
 *
 * @return $this
 */
protected function _prepareForm()
{
    /** @var \BO\Prix\Model\Prix $model */
    $model = $this->_coreRegistry->registry('paquet_paquet');

    /** @var \Magento\Framework\Data\Form $form */
    $form = $this->_formFactory->create(
        ['data' => ['id' => 'edit_form', 'action' => $this->getData('action'), 'method' => 'post']]
    );

    $form->setHtmlIdPrefix('prix_');

    $fieldset = $form->addFieldset(
        'base_fieldset',
        ['legend' => __('General Information'), 'class' => 'fieldset-wide']
    );

    if ($model->getId()) {
        $fieldset->addField('id_paq', 'hidden', ['name' => 'id_paq']);
    }
       // code a barre - Type Text
    $fieldset->addField(
        'code_a_barre',
        'text',
        ['name' => 'code_a_barre', 'label' => __('Barcode'), 'title' => __('Barcode'), 'required' => true]
    );

    //  designation paquet- Type Text

    $fieldset->addField(
        'designation_paq',
        'text',
        ['name' => 'designation_paq', 'label' => __('Packet Designation'), 'title' => __('Packet Designation'), 'required' => true]
    );

    $fieldset->addField(
        'id_pdt',
        'text',
        [
            'name' => 'id_pdt',
            'label' => __('Code Article'),
            'title' => __('Code Article'),
            'required' => true,
            'class' => 'validate-number'

        ]
    )->setAfterElementHtml('
    <script>
        require([
             "jquery",
        ], function($){
            $(document).ready(function () {
                  var input_value = document.getElementById("code_a_barre").value;
                  var res = input_value.substring(0,9);
                  document.getElementById("id_pdt").value = res ;

            });
          });
   </script>
');


    // quantity
    $fieldset->addField(
        'quantity_paq',
        'text',
        ['name' => 'quantity_paq', 'label' => __('Quantity'), 'title' => __('Quantity'), 'required' => true, 'class' => 'validate-number']
    );

    // poids estimé
    $fieldset->addField(
        'poids_paq',
        'text',
        ['name' => 'poids_paq', 'label' => __('Estimated Weight'), 'title' => __('Estimated Weight'), 'required' => true, 'class' => 'validate-number']
    );

    // Reservé
    $fieldset->addField(
        'reservé',
        'text',
        ['name' => 'reservé', 'label' => __('Reserved'), 'title' => __('Reserved'), 'required' => true, 'class' => 'validate-number']
    );

    // in stock
    $fieldset->addField(
        'in_stock',
        'text',
        ['name' => 'in_stock', 'label' => __('IN stock'), 'title' => __('IN stock'), 'required' => true, 'class' => 'validate-number']
    );






    $form->setValues($model->getData());
    $form->setUseContainer(true);
    $this->setForm($form);

    return parent::_prepareForm();
       }
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

`document.getElementById("code_a_barre")` is null

That would suggest there isn't an element on the page which has id="code_a_barre"

As you are using jQuery you could use $('#code_a_barre')

But also remember that magento 2 uses `require-js`.  So you need something like this:

```
require(['jquery'], function($){
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var input = $("#code_a_barre");
        console.log(input_value); // see what comes back
        // $("#code_a_barre").val(); for value
    });
});
```

Comment: how to use require_js and how to call this js in my form in backend and thanks for your replay

Comment: You've done it.  Sorry made my example clearer. Just means that if you are passing `jquery` as `$` you've got to use `$("#code_a_barre")`.